# Decoding Firebase ID token failed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I am trying to restrict my API to only logged users. To do so I am sending firebase token and trying to verify it on server-side exactly how [Google says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) to do.

However, I get an exception like this:

`FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.`

Printing out those tokens on client-side as well as on server-side proves that on both sides they are identical.

Do I miss something?

My code:

```
const checkAuth = (token) => {
  if (token === undefined) return false;
  console.log(token);
  admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(token)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      const uid = decodedToken.uid;
      admin
        .auth()
        .getUser(uid)
        .then(() => {
          return true;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return false;
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};

// example usage

app.get("/fileslist/:id", async function (req, res) {
  const authorized = checkAuth(req.headers.token);
  if (authorized) {
    const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "uploads/" + req.params.id);
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      var array = [];
      if (err) {
        return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
      }
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        array.push(file);
      });
      res.status(200).send(array);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).send();
  }
});
```

And client-side:

```
//getting token
const getToken = () => {
    currentUser
      .getIdToken(true)
      .then(function (idToken) {
        setToken(idToken);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

//calling an api
const getFilesById = async (id, token) => {
  console.log(token);
  return await client.get(
    "/fileslist/" + id,
    {},
    { headers: { token: token } }
  );
};

//api definition
import { create } from "apisauce";

const api = create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3005",
});

export default api;
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `getFilesById`? How are you passing the token in it?

Comment: @Dharmaraj `getFilesById` is called in `useEffect` of React and I pass the token as a parameter

Comment: Can you please confirm the token is logged correctly in console.log?

Comment: @Dharmaraj as I said both on client-side and server-side token is printed out to console and it is identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the entire [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) in the `checkAuth()` function, as follows:

```
const checkAuth = (token) => {
  if (token === undefined) return false;
  console.log(token);
  return admin  // <== see return
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(token)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      const uid = decodedToken.uid;
      return admin  // <== see return
        .auth()
        .getUser(uid)
        .then(() => {
          return true;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return false;
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

---

You could actually have only one `catch` block, as follows:

```
  const checkAuth = (token) => {
    if (token === undefined) return false;
    console.log(token);
    return admin // <== see return
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(token)
      .then((decodedToken) => {
        const uid = decodedToken.uid;
        return admin // <== see return
          .auth()
          .getUser(uid);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      });
  };
```